# Executing commands from windows batch file using Python, without creating batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, wmic

I need to execute below command (and couple of other similar) to collect Windows OS event logs:

```
' wmic nteventlog where filename="appevent" call BackupEventLog C:\appevent.evt '
```

The command executes successfully through cmd prompt. and collects file C:\appevent.evt
But when i use Python   `os.system` or `os.popen` to execute it retruns error.

Also if I create a `.bat` file with the above command and execute the `.bat` using `os.system` it works
properly,

What is going wrong when I execute cmd using `os.system`? 
and How can I execute the command using Python?

Comment: Can you write down the python code that you are using?

Comment: it would help if you show us the error

Comment: I was getting below output: Out Parameters  Instance of _PARAMETERS { ReturnValue = 123; }; ,  It was because i used \a in the path string as mentioned by Dan below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to the `\a` in the string. Escape the `\` in the string by replacing it with `\\`:

```
' wmic nteventlog where filename="appevent" call BackupEventLog C:\\appevent.evt '
```

or use a raw string:

```
r' wmic nteventlog where filename="appevent" call BackupEventLog C:\appevent.evt '
```

Comment: yes, it was because of single \ in the path string.Thanks for your help.